# How to read all data from __MigrationHistory in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to read data from __MigrationHistory table which gets created automatically in Entity Framework 6. Is that possible? Else what is possible way to read data from Migration History table? That to in C#

Comment: SELECT  
 [MigrationId]
 , [ContextKey]
 , CONVERT(XML, DECOMPRESS(Model)) AS [Model EDMX]
 , [ProductVersion] 
FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> what is possible way to read data from Migration History table?

There is a special SQL command just for reading data in a table: [SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql)

Comment: How can we do in C#? sorry I forget to add this in the main question

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't really want to fully hook the migration history table into EF as I wouldn't want people writing to or updating that table which should be handled exclusively by automatic/manual migrations.

So if I needed to access it I would do it with a SQL string to perform exactly what I needed

```
    class MigrationHistoryEntry
    {
        public string MigrationId { get; set; }
        public string ContextKey { get; set; }
        public byte[] Model { get; set; }
        public string ProductVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public void GetMigrations()
    {
        const string GetMigrationSql = "SELECT * FROM __MigrationHistory";

        var migrations = Context.Database.SqlQuery<MigrationHistoryEntry>(GetMigrationSql);
    }
```